# Rails & ActiveRecord: Save Formatting of text block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to save a long multi-paragraph text description in my database in a text attribute. The problem is that when I render this text, all the formatting is missing and it appears as one long string.

Is there any way to keep the line breaks?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it - you can allow html to be processed as your input or you can implement markdown processing of the text field.  I'm kind of verbose but [this article](http://www.mageeworld.com/articles/7) on my blog is actually the second (with a link to the first) about how I implemented markdown in my blog.  I suggest kramdown if you can since it's easier to apply classes

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [simple_format](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)

It will adds formatting rules to the text.

In case if you want to use the formatted description in many places. You can add a method to the model.

For example if you have a model `Post` with field `description`

Then you can add a method in the model so that when ever if you use this method formatting will be applied.

```
  class ContentItem < ActiveRecord::Base

    def formatted_description
      return simple_format(self.description)
    end
  end
```